# Cucumber step not binding with step definitions when using Example block

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am using cucumber with java. When i am trying to pass value from Example block steps are not binding with the step definitions. Throwing steps undefined step reference error on feature file.

Feature File code:

```
Scenario Outline: Verify "Create your account" button on the Profile screen for Guest user
    Given I launched the app
    When I skip the On-boarding flow
    And I tap on continue with free lessons button
    And I tap on Profile tab
    Then the output should be <output>
    Then I should be able to see <text> on profile screen
    And I enter Username as <username> and Password as <username>
    And I tap create your account button on profile screen
    Then I should redirected to Create your account screen

    Examples:
    |  text      | output | username |   pwd    |
    |Register now|   5000 |    sam   | willis   |
```

Step Definition code that i tried:

```
@Then("I should be able to see {string} on profile screen")
    public void i_should_be_able_to_see_register_now_to_save_your_xp_and_access_your_full_profile_on_profile_screen(String text) {
        profile = new Profile();
        Assert.assertTrue(profile.verifyLevelTagForGuestUser(text));
    }

    @Then("I should be able to see <text> on profile screen")
    public void iShouldBeAbleToSeeTextOnProfileScreen(String output) {
        profile = new Profile();
        Assert.assertTrue(profile.verifyLevelTagForGuestUser(output));
    }

    @When("^I enter Username as \"([^\"]*)\" and Password as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void I_enter_Username_as_and_Password_as(String arg1, String arg2) {

    }

    @And("I enter Username as <username> and Password as <username>")
    public void iEnterUsernameAsUsernameAndPasswordAsUsername() {
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Step definition image:

[image: Step definition image]

Comment: Because of the formatting your question is hard to read. Have a look at the https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to make it readable.

Comment: You have  2 times username... that will probably not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is Throwing steps undefined step reference error on feature file as you have *duplicate* column headers with text as ***username***.

```
|  text      | output | username | username |
```

You may like to change it as:

```
|  text      | output | username | password |
```

Comment: when i keep my parameter in "<>" it started working.

Comment: That's because you didn't put quotes around **strings** in your table @adil raza. This makes sense if you got source data like numbers in there as well.

Answer (score 2):

After putting double quotes around the parameter, Now workin fine.Thanks

Feature File code:

```
Scenario Outline: Verify "Create your account" button on the Profile screen for Guest user
    Given I launched the app
    When I skip the On-boarding flow
    And I tap on continue with free lessons button
    And I tap on Profile tab
    Then the output should be "<output>"
    **Then I should be able to see "<text>" on profile screen**
    And I enter Username as "<username>" and Password as "<username>"
    And I tap create your account button on profile screen
    Then I should redirected to Create your account screen

    Examples:
    |  text      | output | username |   pwd    |
    |Register now|   5000 |    sam   | willis   |
```

Comment: But I strongly believe my proposed [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70811655/cucumber-step-not-binding-with-step-definitions-when-using-example-block/70816252#70816252) should have addressed the error for which you have raised the question.